# Can't access functions in another class

Tags: java, function, class, methods

****EDIT**  For everyone saying call it like

```
FunctionTestTest.numberCheck(userNumber);
```

I have tried that numerous times before posting on here it didnt work.

People downvote a question that they cant even answer,  great...

On another project Im working on I couldn't call functions from another class.  Been trying to fix it all day.  Decided to throw up a a few lines of code & try call a function from another class just to make sure i didn't have an unnoticed syntax error in my main project.

can anyone see what the problem is here?

returning this error:

```
cannot find the symbol
symbol: class FunctionTestTest
location: class FunctionTest
```

...

```
public class FunctionTest{ 
  public static void main(String[] args){        

    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    int userNumber = 0;

    System.out.println("Please enter a number between 1 - 10");
    userNumber = input.nextInt();
    FunctionTestTest ft = new FunctionTestTest();
    FunctionTestTest.numberCheck(userNumber);

  }
}
```

and..

```
public class FunctionTestTest{

  public static void main(String[] args){
  }

  public static void numberCheck(int num){
    if (num == 1){
        System.out.println("function works");
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: did you import FunctionTestTest?

Comment: Did you add an `import` statement?

Comment: `new FunctionTestTest(userNumber);` -- there is no constructor like this within this class. In fact the class has no constructor declared at all, and only has a (useless) default constructor.

Comment: Note that you're asking about misunderstandings of foundational issues, problems much better addressed by studying your tutorials and books rather than asking a question here.

Comment: Very much agree with Hovercraft full Of Eels. It seems OP do not know how to place different classes in the same package/project folder thus causing all the confusion.

Answer (score 3):

The error is caused because you are probably using class from another package. In this case you have to import it first before using.

If you are using any IDE there should be a hotkey to fixing your problem.

Also...

You don't need to create an object instance to access static methods of certain class. Simply use:

```
FunctionTestTest.numberCheck(userNumber);
```

**It is not recommended**, but you can call a static method on object instance like:

```
new FunctionTestTest().numberCheck(userNumber);
```

Comment: I did try this earlier netbeans has shortcuts to fix all class imports and selected class imports neither worked.  I get the message no classes found.

Comment: The error you mentioned in your question is compile-time error, so Netbeans should offer you some options for fixing the error.

Answer (score 0):

here you are calling other class constructor and  is not present there:

```
FunctionTestTest ft = new FunctionTestTest(userNumber);
```

also check if FunctionTestTest class present is some other package then import it

Answer (score 0):

> ft.(userNumber);

Your method invocation is incorrect.
Your probably wanted `ft.numberCheck(userNumber)` or `FunctionTestTest.numberCheck(userNumber)`. The latter is preferred as you are incoking a static member.

---

If is it a static method, you just call it as:

```
ClassName.methodName();
```

There is no need to instantiate an object to use a static method like what you did.

**Example:**

```
public class MyClass{
    public static void myMethod(){
        //do whatever..
    }
}

public class OtherClass{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        MyClass.myMethod();  //invoke a static method from another class
    }
}
```

Comment: Done all this and still the same issue

Comment: @Chris Lynch If there are no typo errors. Then check whether the classes are in the same package or same project folder. Check whether the classes are declared as public. So many things you could have checked on your own.

Comment: @ChrisLynch Worse come to worse, create a fresh new project and test with only 2 simple classes. Eventually it will work. Have you experimented all these?

Comment: Yes I have done all this, this is the new project im testing on

Comment: @ChrisLynch Then try writing both classes in the **same** java file and test again. I am sure at least that will work. Work your way from there by moving out the class to another java file and so on. If it still doesn't work, try on another IDE. There are endless things you can try till the problem is fixed.